# Influxdb - group by time(1m) - missing data

Tags: influxdb

I have some data that is coming in from the network every minute from collectd and being entered into my influx database.  Since its via the network it never comes in right on the one minute mark and has some jitter...

I am trying to reconcile this irregular data to one minute intervals but I am seeing some missing gaps, please see example below.

```
> precision rfc3339
>
> select value from snmp_ecio where host = 'my_host_a' and time > now() - 10m
name: snmp_ecio
time                            value
----                            -----
2017-01-22T00:25:59.987735Z     -0.1
2017-01-22T00:27:00.003208Z     -0.1
2017-01-22T00:28:00.047265Z     -0.2
2017-01-22T00:29:00.142676Z     -0.1
2017-01-22T00:30:00.048707Z     -0.3
2017-01-22T00:31:00.211728Z     -0.1
2017-01-22T00:31:59.980621Z     -0.1
2017-01-22T00:32:59.795329Z     -0.1
2017-01-22T00:34:03.206552Z     -0.1
2017-01-22T00:35:00.01463Z      -0.1

> select mean(value) from snmp_ecio where host = 'my_host_a' and time > now() - 10m group by time(1m)
name: snmp_ecio
time                    mean
----                    ----
2017-01-22T00:25:00Z    -0.1
2017-01-22T00:26:00Z
2017-01-22T00:27:00Z    -0.1
2017-01-22T00:28:00Z    -0.2
2017-01-22T00:29:00Z    -0.1
2017-01-22T00:30:00Z    -0.3
2017-01-22T00:31:00Z    -0.1
2017-01-22T00:32:00Z    -0.1
2017-01-22T00:33:00Z
2017-01-22T00:34:00Z    -0.1
2017-01-22T00:35:00Z    -0.1
```

Has anyone experienced this issue or can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you collect your data more frequently (every second or 10 seconds, say) so that you can sum over the time intervals?

Comment: I would like to avoid that because the amount of traffic and scaling issues, the biggest reason though is I want the null values to show up because they indicate to me management to the device was up or down and I can glean availability metrics.I would like to see some sort of consolidate function where I can say `consolidate by (time($interval), offset, heartbeat)` where time would be my polling interval, offset would be from the hour and heartbeat would be +/- the amount of time before invalidating that interval with a null value.  This is what RRDtool does that I am trying to migrate from.

Answer (score 1):

To fill in missing time intervals, use the `fill` operator. Depending on which version you're using, you'll have various options for your fill. If you're using 1.1+, I'd use the `fill(linear)` otherwise, I'd choose `fill(previous)`.

```
SELECT mean(value)
FROM snmp_ecio
WHERE host = 'my_host_a' AND time > now() - 10m
GROUP BY time(1m) fill(linear)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I want influx to fill the missing 1 minute values with null so that I know by looking at the graph that a polling interval was missed and/or count the number of null values to know how many polling intervals were missed in x amount of time.  What I am trying to do is have influxdb round my time intervals to the nearest minute if they are within ~3 seconds or so and mark null anything outside that interval.  This was something that RRDtool did for me, you could pick a step size (polling interval) and also a heartbeat (amount of time before invalidating that polling interval).